# How to remove object from array

Tags: java, jbutton

Please bear within as it might be difficult to understand

I have an array of jbuttons 50 size big, for this example ill use 7  I have jbutton object within 1 2 3 4 6 7 but not 5. These are printed on the screen. I want to remove these jbuttons however all buttons up to 5 are removed while the last two are not.

```
        for(int i = 1; i < 51; i++){ 
            if(seat.buttonArray[i] == null){
            remove(seat.buttonArray[i]);
            seat.buttonArray[i] = null;}
        }
```

Comment: please show more code or a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem; and btw not a rule, but it's a preferred way to start arrays from index 0 instead of 1, that could cause problems.

Comment: This `if(seat.buttonArray[i] == null){seat.buttonArray[i] = null;}` makes no sense at all

Comment: It checks if the object exists into the array, if so remove it and set it to null.

Comment: if it is already null you don't need to set it as null again, you can spare that sentence. This depends indeed on what the method `remove(..)` does but it shouldn't change the input parameters any way

Comment: Whoa I'm really freaking silly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to **remove** element from `array`, assuming you want latter indexes changed after remove. For this purpose, you should use `List`:

```
Iterator buttonIterator = seat.buttonList.iterator();
while (buttonIterator.hasNext()) {
    Object button = buttonIterator.next(); //or more specific type, if your list was generified
    if (button == null) { //or some other criteria, wrote this just as an example
        buttonIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

If using `array` is mandatory, you have two options:

- Set `seat.buttonArray[i]` to `null` value, indicating it has been removed;
- Recreate array each time you deleted something. See [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) javadoc for details, although I do not recommend this approach because of performance considerations.

Comment: I cannot use list as I don't have enough time to do so. I just want to remove the button offscreen and change it to null. that was the original plan of the code.

Comment: I think setting it to `null` should suffice than.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the values in a temp array and then copy what you want back into your original array. Somewhat similar to this:

```
int myArray[50];
int temp[50];
int good;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    myArray[i] = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    temp[i] = myArray[i];
}
good = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (i < 10) {
    } else {
        myArray[good] = temp[i];
        good += 1;
    }
}
```

Looks messier than I first thought... But it essentially does what you're wanting.

Comment: No, I just threw it together and didn't think through it very well. Plus, I didn't have to initialize anything really, since it's already there. You could omit the first loop...