# Arrays of Strings. How to remove a null value

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code.  It returns x with string 'null' instead of removing it completly and shifting all the other code to the left.  For example a {"a", "b", "c", "a"}, "a") is supposed to return {"b", "c"} but instead it returns {"null", "b", "c", "null"}.

```
public String[] wordsWithout(String[] words, String target) 
{
  int count = 0;

  int len = words.length;
  String[] x = new String[(len-count)];

  for(int i = 0; i<words.length; i++)
  {
    if(words[i].compareTo(target) !=0)
     {    
        count++;
     }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i<words.length; i++)
  {
    if(words[i].compareTo(target) !=0)
     {
        x[i] = words[i];
     }   
  } 

  return x;
}
```

Comment: Try using `ArrayList`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove object from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255669/how-to-remove-object-from-array)

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the question [How to remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255669/how-to-remove-object-from-array/23255791#23255791)

I suggest to replace an array with `List` in order to get rid of need to do shifts - `remove()` calls will do it for you.

If you really (I mean, **really**) need an array, you'll have to do some magic with shifting elements to get rid of `null`-filled gaps. For details, see other answers here and in the question I mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without converting it to a ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, but you end up with let's say array with `null` or some other *not-used-element* markers in the end. Although, a golden rule for software development: **Do not reinvent a wheel**, tend to use code created before you when it is possible.

Comment: @user3579634 you would have to create a new array with `null`'s removed

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, to delete an element from an array you need to create a new array only with the desired elements. This is a method to do it:

```
private String[] removeElementAt(int index, String[] original) {
    String[] newArray = new String[original - 1];
    System.arrayCopy(original, 0, newArray, 0, index);
    System.arrayCopy(original, index + 1, newArray, index, newArray.length - index);
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that uses arrays is to:

- Send the array in as a parameter
- Copy all but the value to be removed to a temporary array
- Return the temporary array
- Save the returned array in place of the original
- Let garbage collection remove the original array that now has no reference